# split time between start time and end time for user given minutes as input

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my app I have a drop-down for booking an appointment with psychiatrist. Here the user gives the input as minutes, to talk to the doctor,so in drop-down it should look like a normal timings like 9-10 am, 10-11pm so on till 5pm, so the customer can see the available timing to book the appointment. I'm struggling to get this time split. I have done only the conversion from mins to hours and after that Im struck with the time split.Hoping for some help here, or any valid guidance for proceeding to get the time split.

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
       $scope.calc = function () {
         var time = $scope.timeSelect;
                if (time < 60) {
               var a = (time) + 'm';
                } else if (time % 60 == 0) {
                    var a =  (time - time % 60) / 60 + 'h';
                } else {
                    var a = ((time - time % 60) / 60 + 'h' + ' ' + time % 60 + 'm');
                }
                $scope.result =a;
            }        
            $scope.result='';
});
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you trying to figure out how to add minutes to a time?

Comment: Actually Im  trying split the time for the appointment. say if the person wants to talk to the psychiatrist for 45 mins the drop-down should list the timings like 9-9.45 am , 9.45-10.30am....till the end time 5 pm.So the  person will select the time slot from the drop-down.@jbrown

Comment: If you aren't already, I'd recommend using the Date object and associated methods for adding minutes rather than manipulating a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you are dealing with dates and times I highly recommend using [Momentj.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/). Here is an extremely contrived example to demonstrate how you might use Moment.js to set your time periods.

```js
angular.module("app", ["angularMoment"])
  .controller("ctrl", function($scope, moment) {
    var startingTime = moment().hours(9).minutes(0);
    var endingTime = moment().hours(17).minutes(0);
    $scope.selectedTimeslot = "";
    $scope.intervals = [15, 30, 45, 60, 90, 120];
    $scope.interval = 60;
    $scope.timeslots = [];

    $scope.setTimeSlots = function() {
      $scope.timeslots = [];
      var currentStartTime = angular.copy(startingTime); // use copy to avoid reference issues since we're dealing with objects and not primitives
      while (currentStartTime < endingTime) {
        $scope.timeslots.push(currentStartTime.format("h:mm") + " - " + currentStartTime.add($scope.interval, "minute").format("h:mm"));
      }
    }

    $scope.setTimeSlots();

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/1.0.0/angular-moment.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  Interval in minutes: <select ng-model="interval" ng-change="setTimeSlots()" ng-options="i for i in intervals"></select>
  <br/>Timeslots:
  <select ng-model="selectedTimeslot" ng-options="slot for slot in timeslots">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
  </select><br/><br/>
  Selected timeslot: {{selectedTimeslot}}
</div>
```

Comment: is it for a specific date because you have mention `var startingTime = moment("1/1/2016 9:00 AM PST");  var endingTime = moment("1/1/2016 5:00 PM PST");`

Comment: I was being lazy. I've updated the answer to not use a date when creating the moment objects.

Comment: I tried to get the `minutes` input from the user. So I declared something like this `<input type="number" ng-model="interval"  ng-change="setTimeSlots()">` but the app is struck and also not able to work in the app. Am I doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
function createTimeSlots(startHour, endHour, interval) {
    if (!startHour) {
        endHour = 8;
    }
    if (!endHour) {
        endHour = 20;
    }
    var timeSlots = [],
        dateTime = new Date(),
        timeStr = '';
    dateTime.setHours(startHour, 0, 0, 0);
    while (new Date(dateTime.getTime() + interval * 60000).getHours() < endHour) {
        timeStr = dateTime.getHours() + ':' + dateTime.getMinutes();
        timeStr += '-';
        dateTime = new Date(dateTime.getTime() + interval * 60000);
        timeStr += dateTime.getHours() + ':' + dateTime.getMinutes();
        timeSlots.push(timeStr);
    }
    return timeSlots;
}

console.log(createTimeSlots(9, 18, 45));
```

"9:0-9:45",
"9:45-10:30",
"10:30-11:15",
"11:15-12:0",
"12:0-12:45",
"12:45-13:30",
"13:30-14:15",
"14:15-15:0",
"15:0-15:45",
"15:45-16:30",
"16:30-17:15"

You might wanna add some 0 padding on the getHours() and getMinutes() so that 1:0 will be printed as 01:00.

Comment: This should fix the leading zero issue: ('0' + dateTime.getHours()).slice(-2)

Answer (score 0):

From the question I get a rough idea of what you need, so I hope this helps you on your way. First, I would make a separate function to convert a time (in number of minutes from midnight, as an easy example) to a string, like this:

```
function timeToString(time) {
    if (time < 12 * 60) 
        return (time - time % 60) / 60 + ":" + time % 60 + "am";
    else return (time - time % 60 - 12*60) / 60 + ":" + time % 60 + "pm";
}
```

Then the array to fill the drop-down can be created like this:

```
var times = [];
for (t = startHour * 60; t < endHour * 60; t += duration) {
    times[times.length] = timeToString(t) + ' - ' + timeToString(t + duration);
}
```

Comment: is `timeToString` is a built-in function in angulasjs. sorry Im new to angularjs

Comment: No, it's a javascript function I defined in my first snippet to use it in the second. Angular is based on javascript. It would help you a lot to learn some javascript, for example, [this book](https://www.sitepoint.com/premium/books/javascript-novice-to-ninja)